# Specific command not recognized in only one shell

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, puppet

I'm running Windows7 as OS as my development machine. It has various Shells:

- `cmd`
- Powershell
- Mysysgit GNU Bash <-- this is the one not working
- PuppetLabs Shell
- Nodejs Shell
- PHPStorm built in Terminal

but in *Mysysgit/GNU Bash* the `puppet` command **was not working**.

The funny thing was: When I entered

```
$ where puppet

# Response:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin\puppet.bat
```

in each bash (incl. the Mysysgit) I got the right path. (Only Powershell seems to not really work out how to use `where`). In the PuppetLabs shell I even got a second path

```
$ where puppet

# Response
C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\puppet\bin\puppet
C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin\puppet.bat
```

My systems environment variables were perfectly set up: `echo $PATH` showed me that both included pathes were present. Still `type puppet` did not work.

After I then appended `C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin\puppet.bat`  to my `$PATH` variable and suddenly the `puppet` command got recognized... and failed.

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/bin/puppet:3:in `<main>'
```

The puppet version is `3.5.1` (latest)

I got Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 2.0.x installed on my system. Could it be that there's a conflict with the Ruby installations? It does not appear in any other Shell/Bash/Terminal/Console.

Comment: Is Puppet Version Specific to Ruby 1.8.x??  If so, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/dH9otOmmAmw)

Comment: @ECarterYoung Afaik not. But thanks for the link.

Comment: It seems odd that the batch script is in ...